# Help to cleanup this code

Tags: url-rewriting, get-posts

I am trying to change my attachment page link yo

```
example.com/photos/attachment_ID/post_name/attachment_name
```

can you tell me how to call the parent post name

```
    function wpd_attachment_link( $link, $post_id ){
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    $parent_post = get_post($parent_post_id);
    $rewrite_link = $post->post_name;
    $parent_post_name = $parent_post->parent_post_name;
    $home_url ->rules = '/photos/' . $post->ID . "/$rewrite_link" . "/$parent_post_name";
    return $home_url->rules;
}
add_filter( 'attachment_link', 'wpd_attachment_link', 20, 2 );
```

Comment: Please do not double post. If you need to add more detail to your question, please file an [edit]

Answer (score 0):

[`get_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) returns a [`WP_Post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) object, so you can retrieve the post parent with `$post->post_parent`. You should have a look at the member variables in the `WP_Post` link.